# why css margin property value is null in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is my link function for a directive which `restrict to EA and transclude is true`

```
link : function(scope,element,attrs){

            element.ready(function(){
                var myUL = element.find('ul');
                console.log(myUL.css('margin'));  // prints noting in console.
            });
}
```

my html is

```
<body ng-app="nmrApp">
   <div class="app-container">
     <nmr-dir>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 1" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 2" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 3" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 4" alt="" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 5" alt="" /></a></li>

      </ul>
  </nmr-dir>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS: its loading from external css file called style.css

```
.app-container ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

when i print `myUL` in console it gives me

```
[ul.ng-scope, ready: function, toString: function, eq: function, push: function, sort: function…]
```

`var myUL = angular.element(element.find('ul'));` aslo not worked for me.
get stacked what i am doing wrong? i also set margin to 0 in my css for this ul in the element

Comment: Could you post some of the HTML that is pertinent to this directive?

Comment: Where is the style defined? Is it dynamic or generated from a template or from an external stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1) There may be multiple `ul` elements responding to your find.

Try specifiying with either `.eq(index)`, or an nth child selector.

2) Try wrapping the find in `angular.element` like so:

```
 var myUL = angular.element(element.find('ul'));
```

Comment: thanks for your super fast answer. i already tried both of your tips before posting question ... no luck :(. i should write that. sorry.. editing my questing

Answer (score 0):

First off, have you included jQuery? Angular contains a light version of jQuery which doesn't have all the features of jQuery, and computed styles are one of them.

Secondly, if you look here: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1 it says that shorthand CSS properties aren't supported. You need to use 'margin-top' (or the margin that you're interested in).

Working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    })
    .directive('nmrDir', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.ready(function(){
                    var myUL = element.find('ul');
                    console.log(myUL.css('margin-top'));
                });
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .app-container ul{
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="app-container">
        <nmr-dir>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 1" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 2" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 3" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 4" alt="" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300&amp;text=Image 5" alt="" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nmr-dir>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually i am trying to create my own component in angularjs way that i want to use several angularjs projects, do not want to keep any dependency on jquery. is there any way to get the margin without jquery function. thanks a lot for your answer. the code is 95% similar to my code. ah i did not make any controller for it. if i am not wrong... it is not necessary. right?

Comment: No you don't need a controller, I just had a controller in the example i based it off. If you don't want a dependency on jQuery, you need to implement that functionality yourself, but I'd advise you not do that since the jQuery guys have already solved it once.